# django admin, adding views/context to index page

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have been searching around with no definite guide or answer as I am new to django, I would like to add a variable/context to admin.

I have the following function in my admin:

```
def my_view(request):
    var1 = request.user.get_full_name()
    var2 = SomeModel.objects.filter(name = var1)
    var3 = 0
    for item in var2:
        var3 += 1
```

How can I show/display `var3` in the admin's index page?

Comment: The content of this view will be posted/displayed in the admin's index page, I have tried to search around and it seems that it is not simple as it seems because there many different answers with no definite solution.

Comment: The index admin page has its own view, it's not this one.

Comment: And that would require me to override the index's view?

Comment: It's [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8/django/contrib/admin/sites.py#L397). It's up to you to override it as you wish.